# Calculating the percentage of specific cells in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I can't post image, but I will try to explain. I have a last column in my report that in each row sums previous columns for the same row - simple. 
Now, at the bottom of this column I have the sum of the all of sums (the sum for whole column).

To the right of this last column I want to add the next one, that will calculate the percentage.

```
SUM Percentage

8   8/45*100

4   4/45*100

23  23/45*100

10  10/45*100

=========

45  100
```

No matter how I try to do this I can't seem to get it done properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the total (45) is in a textbox you should be able to divide the value of the field by the value of the textbox.

If the total (45) is in the grouping level of the table you should be able to use an expression with the SUM function specifying the **scope** of the function....something like:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value)/Sum((Fields!MyField.Value),"MyTable")*100
```

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630415%28v=sql.100%29.aspx